# Extracting data from Mongo documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have just started learning Mongo. I am following official documentation to learn about querying Mongo documents.
Now, I have a document in the following structure:

```
{
   "name": "ABC",
   "address":[
        {
          "type": "primary",
          "city": "XYZ",
          "state": "PQR"
        },
        {
          "type": "secondary",
          "city": "XYZ1",
          "state": "PQR1"
        }
     ]
}
```

What I need to do is to extract data from this document to a csv file in below structure:

```
ABC    primary     XYZ    PQR
ABC    secondary   XYZ1   PQR1
```

But all I could do is to extract the data in below structure only (using MongoChef):

```
ABC    primary     XYZ    PQR    secondary   XYZ1   PQR1
```

How do I extract my data in the required structure?  Also what if there is another inner node inside **address** like:

```
{
       "name": "ABC",
       "address":[
            {
              "type": "primary",
              "city": "XYZ",
              "state": "PQR",
              "reachingAddress":[
                 {
                  "modeOfTravel": "AIR",
                  "description": "blah blah"
                 },
                 {
                  "modeOfTravel": "TRAIN",
                  "description": "blah blah blah"
                 }
               ]
            },
            {
              "type": "secondary",
              "city": "XYZ1",
              "state": "PQR1",
              "reachingAddress":[
                 {
                  "modeOfTravel": "AIR",
                  "description": "blah1 blah1"
                 },
                 {
                  "modeOfTravel": "TRAIN",
                  "description": "blah1 blah1 blah1"
                 }
               ]
            }
         ]
    }
```

and I need the data in below structure:

```
ABC    primary     XYZ    PQR   AIR    blah blah
ABC    primary     XYZ    PQR   TRAIN  blah blah blah
ABC    secondary   XYZ1   PQR1  AIR    blah1 blah1
ABC    secondary   XYZ1   PQR1  TRAIN  blah1 blah1 blah1
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: For the first collection, you have to use an [Aggregation query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/index.html). Particularly, look for the stages `$unwind` and `$project` (or `addFields`). You can build an aggregation from the mongo shell _or_ Compass.

Comment: @whoami No. I am still working on it. Will update once resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t used mongochef but traditionally on a mongo shell, i’d use a conbo of aggregator pipeline operations $unwind  $project and $out to create a new collection of documents with name type city state mode of travel and description.

For your second document type you’ve mentioned, use $unwind $unwind $project $out

Below links to help you build aggregator pipeline...

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out

Comment: I used this strategy and got my data in required structure. Thanks